# How can I disable iMessage suggestions in iOS 13’s share menu?

Tags: ios, messages, sharing

In iOS 13, when I try to share something, the first row is all suggestions about who I should text whatever I’m reading to. How can I disable this “feature” so that it stops taking up space in the share menu?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I have found so far is by deleting the conversations with all the suggested contacts.

If you use Signal/Whatsapp to communicate anyway, it is not a big deal. But it is unbelievable that Apple does not allow you to disable this.

Comment: Signal and Whatsapp are allowed to present suggestions too - and they will supersede the iMessage ones if they're used more often

Comment: In most recent versions of iOS, there is actually already an option to remove this annoying feature.